# Queuing and looping buffers in OpenAL

Tags: openal

I have question about queueing buffers in OpenAL.

I have two wave files, let's say for an engine. The first is the sound of the engine starting and the second is the engine running.

What I'm looking for is a way to create a source that plays sound 1 once and then loops sound 2 until alSourceStop() is called.

Is something like this even possible?

Thanks for your help :)
Hans

Answer (score 1):

Here is come code where I stream audio using OpenAL ... the salient line is

```
alSourcei(streaming_source[ii], AL_BUFFER, 0);
```

its written for linux so OSX may require a tweak to header file locations :

https://github.com/scottstensland/render-audio-openal

let me know if your need anything explained ... enjoy

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'll give it a try.